# Suspend laptop when closing lid in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, 18.04, lid

When I close the lid nothing happens in Kubuntu 18.04 and I see no option in Power settings regarding this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `System Settings > Power Management > Energy Saving > Button Event Handling > When laptop lid closed`, change `Do nothing` to `Suspend` from the dropdown.

[image: Suspend on lid close]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve the desired result.

1. Per `Energy Saving` tab: `System Settings` > `Power Management` > `Energy Saving` > `On AC Power` (or another tab) > `Button Event Handling` > `When laptop lid closed`, and choose desired action.
2. Setting per KDE Activity: `System Settings` > `Power Management` > `Activity Settings` > *Your chosen Activity name*, choose radio-button `Use separate settings (advanced users only)` and select the desired action in `Button Event Handling` > `When laptop lid closed`.